# I can not insert (blob data) in Sqlite Android Application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm designing a database in sqlite I followed this [guide](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for db access to the table with three elements (id, text, blob data) , the bolb is an array of bytes, but unfortunately when Use this code:

```
long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null, values);
```

`insertId` always returns -1, then there is an error that I do not understand !

the table is this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
        + " text not null,"+ MOVE + "blob" + ");";
```

algorithm that allows me to convert txt files in a file as a blob bytes to be inserted in the table is this: ( txt --> byte [] array --> blob )

```
public byte[] ConvertByte () 
{
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead =0;
    byte[] dataToSave = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FileName); 
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
          bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }
      byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
      dataToSave = Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
 return dataToSave;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the option of inserting a plain `String` as blob data?

The `Base64.encode()` function has an alternative one that returns a `String` value. I also insert blob data into a table and I have used this alternative and it worked like a charm.